# DCEVM setup in mac + eclipse

Tags: java, dcevm

I have dcevm with its installer by selecting replace by dcevm and dcevm altvm for java. After the installation I face following issues:

1. Eclipse unable to start error Fail to start java virtual machine.
2. Running a class with java cmd I get following error .

objc[10585]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both

jdk1.8.0_112_DCEVM.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10762c4c0) and /JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112_DCEVM.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1077434e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Anyone face following issue?

Comment: Hi, I've similar problem with dcevm 7u111. It looks that hosting jdk is build with different options then dcevm. I've solved in my case by downloading icedTea's hotspot sources, applying DCEVM patches and then I've built it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set mac system java environment,and this can do by jenv,please reference ：[jenv set](http://boxingp.github.io/blog/2015/01/25/manage-multiple-versions-of-java-on-os-x/)